# What is the fastest way to populate a C# DataTable with data stored on columns?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have a `DataTable` object that I need to fill based on data stored in a stream of columns - i.e. the stream initially contains the schema of the DataTable, and subsequently, values that should go into it organised by column.

At present, I'm taking the rather naive approach of

- Create enough empty rows to hold *all* data values.
- Fill those rows per cell.

The result is a per-cell iteration, which is not especially quick to say the least.

That is:

```
// Create rows first...
// Then populate...
foreach (var col in table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>)
{
    List<object> values = GetValuesfromStream(theStream);

    // Actual method has some DBNull checking here, but should 
    // be immaterial to any solution.
    for (var i=0; i<values.Count; i++)
        table.Rows[i][col] = values[i];
}
```

My guess is the backing `DataStorage` items for each column aren't expanding as the rows are added, but as values are added to each column, but I'm far from certain. Any tips for loading this kind of data.

NB that loading all lists first and then reading in by row is probably not sensible - this approach is being taken in the first place to mitigate potential out of memory exceptions that tend to result when serializing huge `DataTable` objects, so grabbing a clone of the entire data grid and reading it in would probably just move the problem elsewhere. There's definitely enough memory for the original table and another column of values, but there probably isn't for two copies of the `DataTable`.

Comment: If you're transposing, I can't see that you can avoid the need to work cell-by-cell///

Comment: That's why I'm operating per cell for the time being - I'm just hoping there's a faster route that's hidden somewhere there. My guess is I'd need to access the underlying `DataStorage` object and copy directly into the array there, but since rows come with IDs that are essentially indices against those arrays, I'm really far from sure what the best way to do that is.

Comment: Ok, so first comment as I'm trying to address this is MUCH better to create a `List<DataRow>` per table, fill it, and *then* add it to the table rather accessing `table.Rows` directly. This avoids a bunch of issues where you have columns that can't accept null values as well as issues where there are expressions involved. A lot of the slowdown the prompted this question looks like it's down to expressions re-computing and the `DataTable` event model than anything else.

Comment: `table.Rows.Add(values.ToArray());` - solve your problem. `DataTable` can add row dynamically.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: I'm afraid it doesn't - I don't have the values for a row yet. I only have values per column (i.e. in a table of `[Name], [Age]`, I'd get all the vales of `[Name]`, then `[Age]`. And I can't load everything upfront because it'll defeat the purpose of chunking serialization operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I haven't found a way to avoid iterating cells, as per the comments above, I've found that writing to `DataRow` items that have already been added to the table turns out to be a bad idea, and was responsible for the vast majority of the slowdown I observed.

The final approach I used ended up looking something like this:

```
List<DataRow> rows = null;
// Start population...
var cols = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>.Where(c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Expression));
foreach (var col in cols)
{
    List<object> values = GetValuesfromStream(theStream);
    // Create rows first if required.
    if (rows == null)
    {
        rows = new List<DataRow>();
        for (var i=0; i<values.Count; i++)
            rows.Add(table.NewRow());
    }
    // Actual method has some DBNull checking here, but should 
    // be immaterial to any solution.
    for (var i=0; i<values.Count; i++)
       rows[i][col] = values[i];
}
rows.ForEach(r => table.Rows.Add(r));
```

This approach addresses two problems:

1. If you try to add an empty `DataRow` to a table that has null-restrictions or similar, then you'll get an error. This approach ensures all the data is there before it's added, which should address most such issues (although I haven't had need to check how it works with auto-incrementing PK columns).
2. Where expressions are involved, these are evaluated when row state changes for a row that has been added to a table. Consequently, where before I had re-calculation of all expressions taking place every time a value was added to a cell (expensive and pointless), now all calculation takes place just once after all base data has been added.

There may of course be other complications with writing to a table that I've not yet encountered because the tables I am making use of don't use those features of the `DataTable` class/model. But for simple cases, this works well.

Comment: Indeed DataRows are very slow if you need to fill a DataTable with more then a dozen rows. A practical alternative is working with object arrays. Example :  object[] oarr = new object[n];  ... ; _dataTable.Rows.Add(oarr). Performancewise this works fine if the DataTable needs to contain over a hundred rows.

Comment: I think this neglects that the stream is of enumerables of values *per column*, so my goal in asking the question was to establish, given a table with partially filled rows, the fastest way to fill them. The answer I settled on was to keep them out of the table, until they were filled anyway. NB that most of this could also have been achieved by `BeginEdit` / `EndEdit` calls to every member route of the table + `BeginLoadData` / `EndLoadData` calls at either end before adding any rows at all. Also, NB that data volumes were in the 100k+ rows, 60+ columns: something like 6m cells to fill!